# Using WM_Close in c#

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to exit a process programatically.
since i am new to this concept. I want to know how to use this below code.

Logic : I will have the process name to be terminated, i shud assign that to
this function.

Say if want to terminate a notepad, how to pass parameter [Process Name] 
to this function ?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    static uint WM_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    public void CloseWindow(IntPtr hWindow)
    {
        SendMessage(hWindow, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Comment: Regarding Mehrdad's response: `CloseMainWindow` uses `WM_CLOSE` to do it's job. The constant for `WM_CLOSE` is 0x10 by the way, not 0xF060.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with Mehrdad's answer but if you really want to re-invent the wheel, then this is how to do it (This is without any error checking etc. Please add that yourself).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

static bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return true;
}


static void Main()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Untitled - Notepad");
    bool ret = CloseWindow(hWnd);
}
```

BTW, [Here is a good place to view Managed declarations of native API's](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Process.CloseMainWindow` instead of manually sending the message. This will send the message to the main window of the process:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// ...

foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe"))
    process.CloseMainWindow();
```

Alternatively, you can use `MainWindowHandle` to get the handle of the main window of a `Process` and send a message to it:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe"))
    CloseWindow(process.MainWindowHandle); // CloseWindow is defined by OP.
```

If you want to kill the process immediately instead of closing the main window, this is not a good approach. You should use the `Process.Kill` method instead.

Comment: @Mehrdad, i want to use WM_Close for requirement purpose. Thanks

Comment: `CloseMainWindow` just sends `WM_Close` to the main window of the process. If you want to manually do that, get the handle with `MainWindowHandle` and manually send the message to that HWND. However, this so called requirement is pretty stupid and with that logic, you should not use anything from .NET libraries and reinvent everything yourself.